# How to implement KAFKA in website activity tracking

Tags: apache-kafka

I am  planning to track all the user activity on my website and kafka seems to be a reliable solution. I am unable to resolve how to send generated events to kafka i.e. how to make my website as a kafka producer.

Comment: Did you checked Kafka documentation?

Comment: @Chiron Yeah they mentioned it as one of the use case but didn't give any details of implementation

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Which language is your website written in?

In Java/Scala the solution is to import the kafka producer dependencies, create a producer, create messages and send them.

I hope this example will help:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example

Comment: Its developed using grails framework. How should I integrate kafka producer code with my web project so as to record events from all my webpages ?

Comment: When an event happens, create a message, put whatever you want in there and send to the producer?

Comment: @user2720864 Are you aware of the fact that Kafka is written in Scala which it is a JVM based language. This means that you can use Kafka classes easily in Groovy?

Comment: yes my mistake .. I withdraw my suggestion .. thanks for pointing out